# NSMutableArray mutation crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, grand-central-dispatch

I'm facing "Collection was mutated while being enumerated" crash in dispatch_async method. This is the code:

```
- (void) addCutObjectFromObject: (Object *) object {
dispatch_async(self.objectsQueue, ^{

    ObjectCut *objectCut = [[[ObjectCut alloc] init] autorelease];
    objectCut.objectId = object.uid;
    objectCut.objectName = object.internal.name;

    @synchronized(self.shownChannelsArray) {
        if (![self.objectsArray containsObject: objectCut])
        {
            [self.objectsArray addObject: objectCut];
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Dispatch_queue is created in the init method like this:

```
_objectsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("objectsQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
 dispatch_retain(_objectsQueue);
```

The code crashes without synchronized block. As far as I know, it should not crash, because there is no loop, and blocks should be added one-by-one waiting for their queue. Can someone explain me, why that is happening?

Comment: what is `self.objectsQueue`?

Comment: Please post how you are creating `self.objectsQueue`

Comment: dispatch_asynch does mean the objects get added asynchronously, thus multiple at a time...

Comment: Who else may be accessing `objectsArray`? If you're throwing blocks around without due consideration it's very possible that one queue mutates while another iterates. Also how blocks are dispatched after being added to a queue depends on the queue type: Himanshu and sbarrow are probably trying to make sure you're creating a serial queue rather than a concurrent one.

Comment: @Tommy yip, thought that was the issue. Polina you need to change DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT to  DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dispatch_queue_create("objectsQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)` creates a concurrent queue. Arbitrarily many blocks dispatched to that queue may execute simultaneously. It's likely that `containsObject:` uses enumeration internally to do a linear search. Therefore one block is in the middle of `containsObject:` while another performs `addObject:`. `NSMutableArray`s are, like the other Foundation mutable objects, not guaranteed to be thread safe.

At the very least you want to use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`. Unless the order is really important to you or your objects don't implement `hash`, `isEqual:`, etc, you should probably also just use a set rather than sort of manually recreating one with an array.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you calling addCutObjectFromObject: from a loop or an enumeration ? 
If It is, you may want to check this part.

Comment: yeah, might be like that, but no. thanks for the answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ah a tricky one.. from my knowledge (and I may be a bit off, so others, feel free to follow up, but this poor chap doesnt have any responses yet..

so when this executes, the async block will not run right away.  It will first be scheduled, I would imagine you are calling this `addCutObjectFromObject` method more than once.  Let's say for example sake that you are calling this method 5 times. Now think about threads.  The first call gets scheduled, eventually begins running, while the second call gets scheduled, eventually starts running, etc.. and this is where the problem starts and I believe your culprit is in `containsObject` and `addObject`.  Under the hood, containsObject is iterating through the array.  Since there are more than 1 thread executing, while one thread is iterating the array, another could be calling `addObject`. Thus generating your crash of 'collection was mutated while being iterating'

Two options for solutions
1) in containsObject, check against a copy of the array rather than the array itself (this is a bad approach because it requires duplicating of the content of the array, BUT it is easy to put in, and for small array sizes, could be a quick fix)

```
if (![self.objectsArray containsObject: objectCut])  => 


if (![[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.objectsArray] containsObject: objectCut])
```

Again, this should stop your sporadic crashes, but this is a BAD SOLUTION (because of the memory duplication)

2) create a temporary array to add the objects to, and once all threads are finished, add the contents of the temporary array to `self.objectsArray`

Answer (score 0):

The error says the reason of crash. It is not allowed to change an array while enumerating.

```
if (![self.objectsArray containsObject: objectCut])
        {
            [self.objectsArray addObject: objectCut];
        }
```

In the above code you were enumerating the array an inserting and object. This is where the error will be given. Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: It would crash anytime this way. It is not in the loop, it crashes just sometimes.